# Clickable div, to hide and show content

Tags: javascript, html, css

not sure why this doesnt work, sometimes its need to be double clicked on div to show content, any suggestion why, and how fix it? . I want it to be hide and show #newpost div, when clicked on toggle1 div etc.thanks

```js
var button = document.getElementById('toggle1'); // Assumes element with id='button'

button.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('newpost');
  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }

};

var button = document.getElementById('toggle2'); // Assumes element with id='button'

button.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('newpost1');
  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="toggle1">Home</li>

    <div id="newpost" class="post">
      <p>Lorem iporem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis id, dolorem dolores obcaecati, repellat quamorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis id, dolorem dolores obcaecati, repellat quamsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Omnis id, dolorem dolores obcaecati, repellat quam!</p>
    </div>

    <li id="toggle2">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>




<div id="newpost" class="post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum ble ble at quam!</p>
</div>

<br>


<div id="newpost1" class="post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis id, dolorem dolores obcaecati, repellat quam!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: for me it works good > https://jsfiddle.net/u1ufcpaj/   . The script is not very correct ( there are easier and more concise ways to do this ) . Also, you have 2 divs with same id `newpost` . Not sure why you did that, but that's not correct

Comment: I copy+paste your code in a `jsfiddle` and it works well, always show/hide the div. How are you testing it? Maybe the fact that you have two "newpost" as id (not allowed) can cause some problems. Avoid duplicated id's, use class instead.

Comment: Its working fine and you should not use the same id on one page twice.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UIMK0
When i click  Home it doesnt always toggle content, sometimes i need double click on it. I removed same id divs.

Comment: I noticed now that first time i need double click on Home/Contact divs to toggle content, then it works always after 1 click.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, maybe your buttons aren't focused at the beginning. Try adding the first line:

```js
document.querySelector('nav').focus();

var button = document.getElementById('toggle1'); // Assumes element with id='button'

button.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('newpost');
  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }

};

var button = document.getElementById('toggle2'); // Assumes element with id='button'

button.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('newpost1');
  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="toggle1">Home</li>

    <div id="newpost" class="post">
      <p>Lorem iporem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis id, dolorem dolores obcaecati, repellat quamorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis id, dolorem dolores obcaecati, repellat quamsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Omnis id, dolorem dolores obcaecati, repellat quam!</p>
    </div>

    <li id="toggle2">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>




<div id="newpost" class="post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum ble ble at quam!</p>
</div>

<br>


<div id="newpost1" class="post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis id, dolorem dolores obcaecati, repellat quam!</p>
</div>
```